# Convert list of dictionaries into HTML table in python 2.7 with out any library

Tags: python, html, list, dictionary

```
items =[{'Remarks': 'id attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Product', 'Id': 'Missing', 'SKU': 'qwO089', 'Title': 'Round Dining Table'}, 
{'Remarks': 'name attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Product', 'Id': '11894', 'SKU': 'FF048SNS', 'Title': None}, 
{'Remarks': 'name attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Bundle', 'Id': '204661', 'SKU': 'FC127', 'Title': 'Missing'}, 
{'Remarks': 'catgroup_id attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Catgroup', 'Id': 'Missing', 'SKU': 'NA', 'Title': 'Ceiling Fan Lighting'}]
```

wanted to convert this list of dictionaries to html table in python2.7

The keys has to be headers and values has to be data for the table

```
html = """<HTML>
<body>
    <h1>Product Details</h1>
    <table>
        {0}
    </table>
</body>
</HTML>"""
tr = "<tr>{0}</tr>"
td = "<td>{0}</td>"
subitems = [tr.format(''.join([td.format(a) for a in item])) for item in items]
print (html.format("".join(subitems)))
```

I tried this but am getting only headers.

Thanks

Comment: The order of entries in a dictionary isn't guaranteed in Python 2.7. I would extract the names of the keys from the first entry and put them in a list. Then first loop over this list to create the header entries. Second loop over the dictionaries and for each dictionary loop over the list of headers to create the appropriate `td` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too busy to do more than a quick "fix" to your code but...

```py
items =[{'Remarks': 'id attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Product', 'Id': 'Missing', 'SKU': 'qwO089', 'Title': 'Round Dining Table'}, 
{'Remarks': 'name attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Product', 'Id': '11894', 'SKU': 'FF048SNS', 'Title': None}, 
{'Remarks': 'name attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Bundle', 'Id': '204661', 'SKU': 'FC127', 'Title': 'Missing'}, 
{'Remarks': 'catgroup_id attribute not found', 'Origin': 'Catgroup', 'Id': 'Missing', 'SKU': 'NA', 'Title': 'Ceiling Fan Lighting'}]   
html = """<HTML>
<body>
    <h1>Product Details</h1>
    <table>
        {0}
    </table>
</body>
</HTML>"""
tr = "<tr>{0}</tr>\n"
td = "<td>{0}</td>"

# get column headers
subitems = [tr.format(''.join([td.format(a) for a in item])) for item in items[:1]]

# get column values
subitems.extend([tr.format(''.join([td.format(item[a]) for a in item])) for item in items])

print (html.format("".join(subitems)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and saved a lot of time